# Calcular expressão matemática em string

Tags: javascript, matemática

Olá, gostaria de saber como posso calcular uma expressão matemática, contida em uma string, em Javascript.
Exemplo: `calc = "(7*2+1)/2";`

Como eu poderia calcular?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Utilizando o método eval.

```
calc = eval("7*2+1/2");
```

Outro exemplo:

```
var x = 10;
var y = 20;
var a = eval("x * y") + "<br>";
var b = eval("2 + 2") + "<br>";
var c = eval("x + 17") + "<br>";

var res = a + b + c;
```

Comment: Obrigado, havia me esquecido da função `eval()`.

Comment: De nada, precisando só chamar.

Answer (score 3):

Usar `eval`, mudar de formato não influencia nada.

**Exemplo:**

```
var Variavel = 7*2+1/2; alert(Variavel);
```

Apresenta o mesmo valor de `alert(eval("7*2+1/2"));`

***É so atribuir o valor sem Aspas.***

Comment: Para visualizar isso acesse o exemplo http://jsfiddle.net/gt7gkcjp/

Comment: eval é considerado um Metodo inseguro e bloqueado dependendo de onde for usa-lo. Ex.: Extensões do Chrome.